# Remove input value when icon button clicked

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this re-usable MUI component, and I want to remove the input text when the icon button is clicked. i would like to know how to achieve this
my code

```
<FormControl variant="outlined">
        <InputLabel htmlFor="outlined-adornment-password">{label}</InputLabel>
        <OutlinedInput
          id={id}
          size="small"
          label={label}
          onChange={(ev) => updateTagName(ev.target.value)}
          endAdornment={
            <InputAdornment position="end">
              <IconButton onClick={handleClickShowPassword} edge="end">
                {type !== requisitionTabForms.Legal ? (
                  <SearchIcon className={classes.iconStyles} />
                ) : (
                  <SendIcon />
                )}
              </IconButton>
            </InputAdornment>
          }
        />
      </FormControl>



   const handleClickShowPassword = () => {
    let dupArr: Array<string> = [...tags];
    console.log(tagName)
    if (dupArr && dupArr.length > 0) {
      dupArr.push(tagName);
    } else {
      dupArr = [tagName];
    }

    updateTags(dupArr);
    if (type === requisitionTabForms.Legal && tagCallBack !== undefined) {
      tagCallBack(dupArr);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me know if I don't understand right but you want to clear input (remove the text) when you click.
As a small snippet is shared I will be assuming some things.

**Assuming** you are not storing the current value in a variable.
*Lets store value*

```
const [currentValue, setCurrent] = useState("");
```

Edit *OutlinedInput*

```
<OutlinedInput
    id={id}
    size="small"
    label={label}
    value={currentValue}
    onChange={(ev) => {updateTagName(ev.target.value); setCurrentValue(ev.target.value)}}
```

*Assuming you are performing this action on SendIcon click*

```
<SendIcon onClick=(e=>{
                        //Some operation
                        setCurrentValue("")
                      })/>
```

Hope this answers your question.

---

EDIT: ASSUMING you are storing current value in ***tagName***

Edit **OutlinedInput**

```
<OutlinedInput
        id={id}
        size="small"
        label={label}
        value={tagName}
        onChange={(ev) => updateTagName(ev.target.value)}
```

*Assuming you are performing this action on SendIcon click*

```
<SendIcon onClick=(e=>{
                        //Some operation
                        updateTagName("")
                      })/>
```